# flutter Floaty Head Body

Tags: flutter, chat

I am trying to add widget inside the FloatyHeadBody to display a picture, but I couldn't, I tried to add it as a parameter in the function FloatyHeadBody but nothing happened can you help me?
**FloatyHeadBody class**

```
    class FloatyHeadBody {
     List<EachRow>? rows;
     FloatyHeadPadding? padding;
     FloatyHeadDecoration? decoration;
     Widget? widget;

  FloatyHeadBody({
  this.widget,
  this.rows,
  this.padding,
  this.decoration,
   });
    
  
    Map<String, dynamic> getMap() {
   final Map<String, dynamic> map = <String, dynamic>{
  'widget':widget,
  'rows': (rows == null)
      ? null
      : List<dynamic>.from(rows!.map((x) => x.getMap())),
  'padding': padding?.getMap(),
  'decoration': decoration?.getMap()
};
   return map;
 }
}
```

**main**

```
    final body = FloatyHeadBody(widget: Container(width :  300,height: 300, color: Colors.red)
   );
```

Comment: Add your code, what you tried to do.

Comment: @Chance here it is thank you for help :)

Comment: I understand, later I will analyze the package and propose another answer.

Comment: They use in  updateFloatyHeadContent the invokeMethod in floaty_head file on the git repositery github.com/Crdzbird/floaty_chathead , that's why we need the getMap, excuse me for all these messages, I am trying to give more information as possible, thank you very much.